# Maven error using Dropwizard with Mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, dropwizard

I am trying to get Dropwizard working with MongoDB.
However, I get a strange maven error when I run `mvn install`.

```
Dependency convergence error for org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.5 paths to dependency are:
+-no.asgari:civilization:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-net.vz.mongodb.jackson:mongo-jackson-mapper:1.4.2
    +-org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.5
and
+-no.asgari:civilization:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-net.vz.mongodb.jackson:mongo-jackson-mapper:1.4.2
    +-de.undercouch:bson4jackson:1.3.0
      +-org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.7.4
```

My pom looks like this:

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <dropwizard.version>0.7.1</dropwizard.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
            <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-views-freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-assets</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- !dropwizard -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.11-beta1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.11-beta1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-examples</artifactId>
            <version>3.11-beta1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.vz.mongodb.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-jackson-mapper</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
        </dependency
```

This is just a part of my pom. There are no other dependancies other than test.

Comment: why are you using net.vz.mongodb.jackson as a jackson mapper? or how does it integrate in your project?

Comment: What am I supposed to use? I thought this was the default Mongodb mapper?

Comment: I've added an answer that might prove useful

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Spring or some other third party library that offers seamless integration with MongoDB you could use MongoJack as a jackson mapper.

Step 1 - the maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongojack</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongojack</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0</version>
  <type>bundle</type>
</dependency>
```

Step 2 - the repository:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>oss-sonatype</id>
        <name>oss-sonatype</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Step 3 - mapping POJOs:

```
public class MyObject {
  private String id;
  @ObjectId
  @JsonProperty("_id")
  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }
  @ObjectId
  @JsonProperty("_id")
  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

Step 4 - inserting:

```
JacksonDBCollection<MyObject, String> coll = JacksonDBCollection.wrap(dbCollection, MyObject.class,
        String.class);
MyObject myObject = ...
WriteResult<MyObject, String> result = coll.insert(myObject);
String id = result.getSavedId();
MyObject savedObject = result.getSavedObject();
```

Step 5 - query:

```
MyObject foundObject = coll.findOneById(id);
```

Other examples and detailed explanation for the above can be found on the [MongoJack official website](http://mongojack.org/tutorial.html)

And as a side-note, if Spring is an option for you please take a look at the [Spring-Data-MongoDB Project](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/)

**EDIT:**
After reading a bit i found out that the mapper you are using is in fact an older version of MongoJack. So upgrading your code to use an updated version of it would surely benefit your project.

Comment: Thank you! This helped. I was using a old mapper indeed. Just found that example. I will try what you suggest here. I am not using Spring, and will not use Spring either. Do you suggest using MongoJack, or should I first try to use MongoDB Java Driver without MongoJack?

Comment: @Shervin normally it should work with the simple MongoDB Java driver + the jackson fasterxml (for serializing/deserializing json), but if you think the MongoJack features will be more suitable go with that. anyways it uses the same jackson serializer as I've suggested